# Stored Procedure to calculate and return two rows (credit / debit)

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have been working on a report for a financial system that I've inherited and the code is a real mess. Currently the current code performs multiple queries and executes procedures to build a public list which is then used as a datasource for a DevExpress grid control. Having worked on other sections of this application I found it far more efficient to perform all the calculations in the database since they are fairly basic. Retrieving and manipulating the figures has been quite straightforward but I'm stuck at the moment trying to complete the final aspect of the report: **the ledger**.

Essentially, I need to perform calculations and based on the values being positive or negative, show those values in one of two rows (debit or credit). Having only just learned stored procedures, I'm stuck on how to do this. I have my code and all declared variables "set" but I don't know how to "allocate" them to rows and since there isn't a table for this, I'm really unsure as to how I'll go about this.

Can anyone steer me in the correct direction? I'm not asking for someone to code for me, I don't know how to define what I need to do in order to research a method.

Below is the current select statement that outputs the correct figures but all in one row:

```
set @OpeningBalance = -3; /**some real calculations here**/


if @OpeningBalance is null
    begin
        set @OpeningBalance = 0
    end;

set @ReserveAmount = 569119.60; /**in place of the real calculations **/

set @ReserveTotal = (@OpeningBalance + @ReserveAmount);

set @ReserveRate =  0.25; /**in place of the select statement calculations **/

set @RequiredReserve = (@ReserveAmount);

set @ReserveRefund = (@ReserveTotal - @RequiredReserve );

set @UnfinancedInvoices = 21026087.59; /**in place of the real calculations **/

set @ReserveBalance = (@RequiredReserve + @UnfinancedInvoices);

SELECT  @OpeningBalance as 'OpeningBalance', 
        @ReserveAmount as 'ReserveAmount', 
        @ReserveTotal as 'ReserveTotal', 
        @ReserveRate as 'ReserveRate', 
        @RequiredReserve as 'RequiredReserve',
        @ReserveRefund as 'ReserveRefund',
        @UnfinancedInvoices as 'UnfinancedInvoices', 
        @ReserveBalance as 'ReserveBalance'
END
```

Using the above fields, I need an output similar to the mock up below:
[image: Mockup of the desired output]

I would prefer "0.00" values as opposed to blank spaces

I thought that perhaps I could have an ID for the select statement but I'm not even sure if what I need to do is possible in SQL (although I'd be surprised if it wasn't)

**PLEASE HELP!**

Comment: Please could you provide a sample of how you would like the output to look? I cannot visualize the expected output from the question.

Comment: Yes you definitely need to provide sample data. Are you saying you need to return two rows instead of one?

Comment: @LunarSage please review, I've added the mockup for the output.

Comment: Thats a start, but what are the rules to get that on different rows. You can definitely do what you want if you can only explain it. Some ways to turn two rows into one: `UNION ALL` or `CROSS JOIN`

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Yes I'm familiar with `UNION ALL` having used it to merge two queries against the same table with differing scenarios - it's brilliant! Taking into account the answer below, I'm thinking I could declare two tables and then `UNION ALL` but I wonder if that's going to backfire later down the line since it's probably not the most efficient. In terms of rules, I would assign the values positive for the top row and negative for the bottom row.

Comment: If you use `CROSS JOIN` you can save yourself repeating a bit of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still a little unsure about the exact format you are looking for, but the below puts the value for each variable into one of the two rows based on it being positive or negative. I added the `Type` column for clarity, and assumed the first and last columns were always displayed in both rows.

```
SELECT  'Credit' as [Type],
    @OpeningBalance as [OpeningBalance], 
    CASE WHEN @ReserveAmount >= 0 THEN @ReserveAmount ELSE 0.00 END as [ReserveAmount], 
    CASE WHEN @ReserveTotal >= 0 THEN @ReserveTotal ELSE 0.00 END as [ReserveTotal], 
    CASE WHEN @ReserveRate >= 0 THEN @ReserveRate ELSE 0.00 END as [ReserveRate], 
    CASE WHEN @RequiredReserve >= 0 THEN @RequiredReserve ELSE 0.00 END as [RequiredReserve],
    CASE WHEN @ReserveRefund>= 0 THEN @ReserveRefund ELSE 0.00 END as [ReserveRefund],
    CASE WHEN @UnfinancedInvoices >= 0 THEN @UnfinancedInvoices ELSE 0.00 END as [UnfinancedInvoices], 
    @ReserveBalance as [ReserveBalance]
UNION ALL
SELECT  'Debit' as [Type],
    @OpeningBalance as [OpeningBalance], 
    CASE WHEN @ReserveAmount <= 0 THEN @ReserveAmount ELSE 0.00 END as [ReserveAmount], 
    CASE WHEN @ReserveTotal <= 0 THEN @ReserveTotal ELSE 0.00 END as [ReserveTotal], 
    CASE WHEN @ReserveRate <= 0 THEN @ReserveRate ELSE 0.00 END as [ReserveRate], 
    CASE WHEN @RequiredReserve <= 0 THEN @RequiredReserve ELSE 0.00 END as [RequiredReserve],
    CASE WHEN @ReserveRefund <= 0 THEN @ReserveRefund ELSE 0.00 END as [ReserveRefund],
    CASE WHEN @UnfinancedInvoices <= 0 THEN @UnfinancedInvoices ELSE 0.00 END as [UnfinancedInvoices], 
    @ReserveBalance as [ReserveBalance]
```

Comment: Thank you Lunar, this was what I had thought initially but wasn't able to determine how it would work. When I use your select statement I get the following errors relating to the `@OpeningBalance` after the `[Type]`

`Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 59
Incorrect syntax near '@OpeningBalance'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 69
Incorrect syntax near '@OpeningBalance'.`

Comment: I missed a comma, give it another shot

Comment: Thanks, this looks perfect

Comment: Not a Problem !

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add an additional column to your query that assigns one value for your first row and another for your second row, which you then group on:

```
declare @t table(amt int, cust nvarchar(50));
insert into @t values(1,'c1'),(-5,'c1'),(4,'c1'),(7,'c2'),(-9,'c2');

select cd
      ,Customer
      ,TotalAmount
from(
    select case when amt < 0 then 'c' else 'd' end as cd
          ,cust as Customer
          ,sum(amt) as TotalAmount
    from @t
    group by case when amt < 0 then 'c' else 'd' end
            ,cust
    ) a
order by Customer
        ,cd;
```

Output:

```
+----+----------+-------------+
| cd | Customer | TotalAmount |
+----+----------+-------------+
| c  | c1       | -5          |
| d  | c1       | 5           |
| c  | c2       | -9          |
| d  | c2       | 7           |
+----+----------+-------------+
```

Comment: Thanks, this works when I execute it in a query editor, can you explain the logic here so I can apply it to my scenario. I think I understand it but I would appreciate an example like yours with two columns

Comment: @Daniel  You are essentially adding a calculated column to your output, that is set based on the value of your amount. If you add some dummy data to your question I can be more specific and show you a more fitting example.  I have edited my answer to try to better show what is happening.

Comment: I've updated my question however the answer from LunarSage seems to work exactly as required. Unless you have a reason as to why that's not the most efficient way to do it, thank you for your effort!